# C# GUI to highlight rows from a file? Existing code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not a C# developer (done some, but not an expert) but I would like to write a simple GUI which loads a file and, based on some basic rules, colors the background rows accordingly. Perhaps a few tooltips when hovering over words.

What would be the simplest way to do this? Are there any libraries already doing most of the work?

Comment: Try something first and then come back when you are stuck.  What you explained is pretty straight forward and simple if you gave it a try.  System.IO to read files, Rich Textbox for coloring words ect...

Comment: You can show your desired content in a `WebBrwoser` control.

Comment: I wonder how the answer is down voted without any comment while I can't see anything wrong with the answer and I think it is a good option.

Comment: @Sorceri using `RichTextBox` can not simply satisfy the requirement for tooltip.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  down voted for no effort is my guess and yes you can use a tooltip with a richtextbox, you dynamically create them depending on what is going on, events, selections ect.  Takes effort but it can be done.

Comment: @Sorceri Yes it can be done, But I think the idea of using web browser is really good and flexible and such rush to the answer because of  "OP no effort" is really disappointing.

Comment: Let me know if you had any question about the answer or if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1 - WebBrowser Control**

As an option you can show your desired content in a `WebBrwoser` control.
You can simply create the html content in a string variable and then set `webBrowser1.DocumentText`.

- Show lines in `<div>` elements
- Show tooltip using `title` attribute of the element
- Show highlight by createing a class that changes for example `background-color` of the element and assign it to `class` attribute of the elements that you want to highlight

An example of the content can be:

```
<html>
<head><title>Text</title></head>
<style>
    .highlight
    {
        background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>Line 1</div>
    <div class="highlight" title="Some tooltip">Line 2</div>
    <div>Line 3</div>
    <div class="highlight" title="Some tooltip"> Line 4</div>
    <div>Line 5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That will result in:

[image]

- You can use `style="background-color:yellow"` or some other color for each row.
- You can simply set `webBrowser1.DocumentText` when you want to change the content and the highlights when you need.
- You can also simply manipulate `DOM` using `WebBrwoser` properties and methods.
- As an idea to render contents, you can create a model to render the content simply, for example:

```
public class LineItem
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    public bool Highlight { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("<div {0} title=\"{1}\">{2}</div>" , 
            HighLight==true?"class=\"highlight\"":"" , 
            ToolTip, 
            Content);
    }
}
```

**Option 2 - RichTextBox Control**

As another option you can use a `RichTextBox`:

- Highlight text using `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor`
- Find the character under mouse using `richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition` and this way you can find the word or the line and show a Tooltip based on text.

Comment: To the down voter, consider a comment about the reason of down vote or share a better answer.

Comment: how is an HTML-based answer any good to a question tagged `winforms`? I might as well have provided a WPF-based answer, which would be a thousand times more suitable than your approach, and yet I didn't because this is winforms, and I can only provide a WPF-based answer after the OP explicitly agrees upon or requires that.

Comment: @HighCore An html based answer is OK because it's completely better than `RichTextBox` to solve this problem and the OP can use [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040(v=vs.85).aspx) control to use this aproach. Also a `WPF` based answer is OK, because the OP can  use [`ElementHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) and host the wpf control to windows forms.  Why not use these approaches when both of them are better than using `RichTextBox` and both approaches have good interoperability with windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `RichTextBox` and `SelectionBackColor`